# FancyTree - Unable to load select extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancytree

I'm attempting to add checkboxes to my fancytree view.

My scripts section has this:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.fancytree-all.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/src/jquery.fancytree.filter.js"></script>
```

fancytree-all.min.js is version 2.17.0, downloaded from github today, using the /dist/ folder.

The implementation of fancytree starts like this:

```
    $("#folderTree").fancytree({
        extensions: ["dnd", "filter", "select"],
        checkbox: true,
        selectMode: 3,
        ...
    });
```

The error in my console is this: 
`Uncaught Error: Could not apply extension 'select' (it is not registered, did you forget to include it?)`

I've checked for a file named jquery.fancytree.select.js, but it doesn't seem to exist. I've also checked the demo (http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/sample-select.html) and I can not spot any differences between their source and mine. What am I missing?

edit: Found the answer, turns out specifying the "select" extension is no longer needed.

Comment: I suppose you also have jQuery included, but how about jQueryUI?

Comment: Thanks @AdrianRoman. I do have both included. The problem was that I am on the latest build and the demo site was using a build a few versions old. Somewhere in between the way the "select" extension gets accessed was changed.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying `"select"` in your extensions is not required/does not work for the current version of fancytree.